# Hide vimeo user account logo on embedded videos

Tags: javascript, html, vimeo

I did some research on how to remove logo which removes the Vimeo logo on the bottom right corner. But I want to remove the user logo and author from embedded vimeo video. Is this possible? If yes how can I do that?

[image: vimeo]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes this is possible. However, it depends on the video's settings. If you are the video owner, you can control these attributes in the `Embed` Section of the Settings page in the `Your Details` section. [image: Image of the embed settings page.]
As you can see, you have the option to keep these on or turn them off for all embeds. However, if you turn on the `Let Users Decide` then by default the elements are on but can then be turned off by a user either using the URLs params or embed options of `byline`, `title` and `portrait`, as described [in this help article](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001494447-Using-Player-Parameters).

If you are not the videos owner or only have a basic account (which only allows control of certain embed settings) then there is not much you can do.

Answer (score 14):

You can hide it without being the video owner by using URL parameters in your embed URL.

Here is a official list of all the available parameters: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001494447-Using-Player-Parameters

So adding ***&portrait=0&byline=0*** at the end of your embed URL will remove the username and avatar.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer. Your approach might really save the humanity and I really mean it.

Comment: That works but I had to change the first ampersand & to a question mark ?. Normal url parameter convention yeah. Thanks mate.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, if your parameter is the first parameter in the URL, you need to replace the first & by ?, thanks for pointing it out!